# Python function to return mean or mode of a pandas dataframe column, depending on the column data type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write a python function to return mean or mode of a pandas dataframe column, depending on the column data type. If the df column contains strings it should return the mode. If the df column contains numerals it should return the mean.

This is my code:

```
def calc_mean_mode(df, column_name):
    mean = round(df[column_name].mean(), 2)
    mode = df[column_name].mode()
    
    if df[column_name].dtypes == 'O': 
        return mode
    else:
        return mean
```

However I keep getting a type error:
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: Use `isinstance(df[column_name], str)`  and `int`, respectively.

Comment: I am faced with the same question and get a false on the test result. df has Embarked under Age and df_clean has actual ages. could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def calc_mean_mode(df, column_name):
   if df[column_name].dtypes == 'O': 
       output = df[column_name].mode()
   else:
       output = round(df[column_name].mean(), 2)

   return output
```

Comment: Kindly provide an explaination to your solution.